# vue.js resizable table columns

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css

Hello dear stackoverflow users.
I'm trying to create a resizable table and the technologies I use are vue2 and tailwindcss.
But the problem I have is that I can extend the columns in the table as much as I want, but I cannot narrow them as much as I want.
What I want is for the columns to be narrowed as much as I want, up to a minimum of 40px, and if the content does not fit, three dots should be placed at the end.

my code:

```js
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    
    mounted() {
        this.makeTableResizable();
    },
    methods: {
       
        makeTableResizable() {
            const table = this.$refs.resizableTable;
            const columns = table.querySelectorAll("th .resizable-column, td .resizable-column");

            let startX;
            let startWidth;
            let columnToResize;

            columns.forEach((column, index) => {
                column.style.position = "relative";

                const div = document.createElement("div");
                div.style.position = "absolute";
                div.style.height = "100%";
                div.style.width = "10px";
                div.style.top = "0";
                div.style.right = "0";
                div.style.cursor = "col-resize";
                column.appendChild(div);

                div.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
                    startX = e.pageX;
                    startWidth = column.offsetWidth;
                    columnToResize = column;

                    document.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
                    document.addEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);
                });
            });

            function onMouseMove(e) {
                if (columnToResize) {
                    const width = startWidth + (e.pageX - startX);
                    columnToResize.style.width = `${width}px`;
                }
            }

            function onMouseUp() {
                columnToResize = null;
                document.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
                document.removeEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);
            }
        },


    },

})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');

* {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;

    &:focus {
        outline: none;
        box-shadow: none!important;
    }
}

body {
    overflow-x: hidden;

    #personDetailPagination,
    .pagination {
        li {
            &.active {
                a {
                    color: #106FDF;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    .scrollbar-none {
        &::-webkit-scrollbar {

            display: none;
        }
    }

    .table-pagination {
        span {
            &.active {
                color: #96A3B3;
            }
        }
    }

    #messagePagination {
        li {
            &.active {
                a {
                    color: #616573;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    .section {
        .section-indicator {
            position: relative;
            z-index: 1;

            &::after {
                position: absolute;
                width: 0.3px;
                height: 100%;
                top: 0;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translateX(-50%);
                content: '';
                background-color: #96A3B3;
                z-index: -1;
            }
        }
    }

    .checkboxRow {
        input {
            &:checked {
                ~.check {
                    .checked {
                        opacity: 1;
                        pointer-events: auto;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    .checkboxToggler {
        span.check {
            position: relative;
            cursor: pointer;

            &::after {
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                top: 0;
                width: 18px;
                height: 100%;
                content: '';
                background-color: #fff;
                z-index: 1;
                border-radius: 9999px;
                transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
                box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
            }
        }

        input {
            &:checked {
                ~.check {
                    &::after {
                        left: 100%;
                        transform: translateX(-100%);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

table {
    thead {
        th {
            &:not(:first-child) {
                border-left: 1px solid #99A3B1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.min.js"></script>


<div class="overflow-x-auto">
                                <h2 class="text-xl font-medium text-[#90C470]">Tablo Başlık</h2>
                                <div class="relative w-full mt-5 overflow-x-auto scrollbar-none">
                                    <table ref="resizableTable" class="w-full text-left min-w-max">
                                        <thead class="text-xs bg-[#D2DAE5] text-[#616573] whitespace-nowrap ">
                                            <tr>
                                                <th scope="col"><div class="px-6 py-4 resizable-column line-clamp-1">Bölüm</div></th>
                                                <th scope="col"><div class="px-6 py-4 resizable-column line-clamp-1">Doktor Adı</div></th>
                                                <th scope="col"><div class="px-6 py-4 resizable-column line-clamp-1">Dur.</div></th>
                                                <th scope="col"><div class="px-6 py-4 resizable-column line-clamp-1">Myn.</div></th>
                                                <th scope="col"><div class="px-6 py-4 resizable-column line-clamp-1">Tarih</div></th>
                                                <th scope="col"><div class="px-6 py-4 resizable-column line-clamp-1">Saat</div></th>
                                                <th scope="col"><div class="px-6 py-4 resizable-column line-clamp-1">Açıklama</div></th>
                                                <th scope="col"><div class="px-6 py-4 resizable-column line-clamp-1">Hasta Adı</div></th>
                                                <th scope="col"><div class="px-6 py-4 resizable-column line-clamp-1">Kimlik No</div></th>
                                                <th scope="col"><div class="px-6 py-4 resizable-column line-clamp-1">Dosya No</div></th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody class="text-xs whitespace-nowrap">
                                            <tr class="bg-white">
                                                <td scope="row">
                                                  <div class="resizable-column px-6 py-1.5 line-clamp-1">  Beslenme Diyet</div>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <div class="resizable-column px-6 py-1.5 line-clamp-1">
                                                        Nur Seda Güler
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                  <div class="resizable-column px-6 py-1.5 line-clamp-1">
                                                    <div class="w-5 h-5 min-w-[20px] min-h-[20px] bg-red-500 rounded-full flex items-center justify-center text-white">
                                                        <img src="../assets/images/svg/times-white.svg" class="w-2" alt="">
                                                    </div>
                                                  </div>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                   <div class="resizable-column px-6 py-1.5 line-clamp-1">
                                                    <div class="w-5 h-5 min-w-[20px] min-h-[20px] bg-red-500 rounded-full flex items-center justify-center text-white">
                                                        <img src="../assets/images/svg/times-white.svg" class="w-2" alt="">
                                                    </div>
                                                   </div>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <div class="resizable-column px-6 py-1.5 line-clamp-1">
                                                        27.05.2020
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <div class="resizable-column px-6 py-1.5 line-clamp-1">
                                                        11:20
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <div class="resizable-column px-6 py-1.5 line-clamp-1">
                                                        Telefon randevulu hasta
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <div class="resizable-column px-6 py-1.5 line-clamp-1">
                                                        isa öztaş
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <div class="resizable-column px-6 py-1.5 line-clamp-1">
                                                        1111111111
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <div class="resizable-column px-6 py-1.5 line-clamp-1">2132131231</div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```